# How to add a field into a snippet in Comfortable Mexican Sofa

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I plan to use snippets in Comfortable Mexican Sofa to store email templates. But is there a way to add a field into a snippet. I would use it to store the subject of the email. Would be good to have also the subject in the cms so that our editors can change it if they feel like it.

By default snippets seem to have only two fields 'Label' and 'Identifier'. And of course the 'Content'. I would like to add also a 'Subject' String into the fields.

Comment: Why don't you use 'Label' to set the subject of an e-mail? This way you wouldn't have to modify the CMS.

Comment: Originally I thought that when I change the label it will also change the identifier, but it seems to be the case only before the snippet is saved for the first time. I think I could use the Label. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple Three Step Process:**

**1:**

```
rails g migration AddSubjectToComfyCmsSnippets subject:string
```

**2:**

```
rake db:migrate
```

**3:**

create `app/views/comfy/admin/cms/snippets/_form.html.haml` with the following content:

```
- content_for :right_column do
  = render 'comfy/admin/cms/files/index'
= render :partial => 'comfy/admin/cms/partials/snippet_form_before', :object => form
= form.text_field :label, :data => {:slugify => @snippet.new_record?}
= form.text_field :identifier, :data => {:slug => true}
= form.text_field :subject
= form.text_area :content, :data => {'cms-rich-text' => true}
= render :partial => 'comfy/admin/cms/categories/form', :object => form
= render :partial => 'comfy/admin/cms/partials/snippet_form_after', :object => form
= form.form_group :class => 'form-actions' do
  = form.submit t(@snippet.new_record?? '.create' : '.update'), :class => 'btn btn-primary'
  = link_to t('.cancel'), comfy_admin_cms_site_snippets_path, :class => 'btn btn-link'
```

Now you can reference the subject in your app like so:

```
Subject: #{@snippet.subject}
```

***Monkey patch to get fixtures working:***

create `config/initializers/cms_monkey_patch.rb` with the following contents:

```
ComfortableMexicanSofa::Fixture::Snippet::Importer.class_eval do
    def import!
      Dir["#{self.path}*/"].each do |path|
        identifier = path.split('/').last
        snippet = self.site.snippets.find_or_initialize_by(:identifier => identifier)

        # setting attributes
        categories = []
        if File.exists?(attrs_path = File.join(path, 'attributes.yml'))
          if fresh_fixture?(snippet, attrs_path)
            attrs = get_attributes(attrs_path)

            snippet.label = attrs['label']
            snippet.subject = attrs['subject']
            categories    = attrs['categories']
          end
        end

        # setting content
        %w(html haml).each do |extension|
          if File.exists?(content_path = File.join(path, "content.#{extension}"))
            if fresh_fixture?(snippet, content_path)
              snippet.content = extension == "html" ? 
                ::File.open(content_path).read : 
                Haml::Engine.new(::File.open(content_path).read).render.rstrip
            end
          end
        end

        # saving
        if snippet.changed? || self.force_import
          if snippet.save
            save_categorizations!(snippet, categories)
            ComfortableMexicanSofa.logger.info("[FIXTURES] Imported Snippet \t #{snippet.identifier}")
          else
            ComfortableMexicanSofa.logger.warn("[FIXTURES] Failed to import Snippet \n#{snippet.errors.inspect}")
          end
        end

        self.fixture_ids << snippet.id
      end

      # cleaning up
      self.site.snippets.where('id NOT IN (?)', fixture_ids).each{ |s| s.destroy }
    end
  end
end

ComfortableMexicanSofa::Fixture::Snippet::Exporter.class_eval do
    def export!
      prepare_folder!(self.path)

      self.site.snippets.each do |snippet|
        snippet_path = File.join(self.path, snippet.identifier)
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(snippet_path)

        # writing attributes
        open(File.join(snippet_path, 'attributes.yml'), 'w') do |f|
          f.write({
            'label'       => snippet.label,
            'subject'       => snippet.subject,
            'categories'  => snippet.categories.map{|c| c.label}
          }.to_yaml)
        end

        # writing content
        open(File.join(snippet_path, 'content.html'), 'w') do |f|
          f.write(snippet.content)
        end

        ComfortableMexicanSofa.logger.info("[FIXTURES] Exported Snippet \t #{snippet.identifier}")
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: One big drawback while trying this out. When exporting the cms into fixtures using `rake comfortable_mexican_sofa:fixtures:export` the subject field is not exported from the database. Would there be an equally simple step to make the export command to include custom database columns? And the same for import? We use the fixtures to publish the site from staging to production.

Comment: @Mika.  I added a solution which, I am fairly confident, will get fixtures working.  I did not test it.  If you try it and it does not work, please let me know.  I simply added two lines to [this](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/blob/master/lib/comfortable_mexican_sofa/fixture/snippet.rb) code

Comment: Btw, I feel that my suggestion above is becoming a little bit heavy-handed.  Personally, I would try to avoid such modifications when possible.  If you implement this and it works, you might just want to be vigilant when updating the cms gem.

Comment: Thank you. This certainly looks like a possible way to go. My current solution is to have a separate snippet for the subject. While it works without modifications to the CMS code, it soon gets a little messy in the snippet section. I will need to get back to this after I have finished some higher priority tasks.